# My JPQL query with Outer Join returns empty list while using GroupBy, OrderBy and Sum Function

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data, jpql, spring-data-jpa

This is my Product entity:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private Category category;

    ...
}
```

And this is the productOrder junction table for the relation product-order:

```
@Entity
public class ProductOrder {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductOrderId pk;

    @Min(value = 1)
    private int quantity; 

    ...
}
```

And this is the embeddedId class:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProductOrderId {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "orderr_id")
    private Order order;

    ...
}
```

I have this JPQL Query works perfectly which finds all the products from a category, sorting them based on their total sold quantity. Since it is a outer join, i get also the ones which haven't been sold yet:

```
@Query(value = "select p, sum(po.quantity) as total_quantity " + 
        "from ProductOrder po " +
        "right join po.pk.product p where p.category = (?1) " +
        "group by p.id, p.name " +
        "order by total_quantity desc nulls last")
Page<Object[]> findBestSellerProductsByCategory(Category category, Pageable pageable);
```

The problem is, when there is not any sold product in a category, i get an empty page. So in order to use this query, my category has to have at least 1 sold product, then i get also the others which haven't been sold yet. What is the problem here?

Since i make a "select from junctionTable (ProductOrder)", when there is not any element from the category in this table, i get an empty list as i understand. But i could not make it the other way around "select from product", since product has no reference of productOrder table, i cannot make a join relationship in that case..

**INFO**: When i remove the groupBy, it works. I get my products from a category even if none of them is sold yet.

```
@Query(value = "select p " + 
        "from ProductOrder po " +
        "right join po.pk.product p where p.category = (?1)")
Page<Object[]> findProductsByCategory(Category category, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Have you tried the Select statement directly against the database? Are you sure you can use columns that are not in the SELECT in the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: The query works when i have at least 1 sold product. So i assume that is not the problem, since "select p" selects all the columns including those in the group by clause (p.name, p.id).